# Unable to paste data and save in webpage using vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net

The automation which I'm working requires me to open a webpage, click a tab and paste some data in text area and click save button. I'm using vb .net Visual Studio 2017 and this is my HTML

```
<li><a href="#tab-overview"><span>Overview</span></a></li>
<li id="tab-vendor-link" style="display:none">
   <a href="#tab-vendor"><span>Vendor Info</span></a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="#tab-correspondence" id="tab_correspondence">
   <span>Correspondence &nbsp;
   <img id="update_correspondence_link" src="/images/small_refresh.png?
      v=420740.386111111&killcache=201108172214" border="0" 
      class="expandable"/>
   <img src="/images/small_load.gif?
      v=420740.386111111&killcache=201108172214" 
      id="update_correspondence_indicator" 
      style="display:none;" align="top" /></span></a>
</li>
<li><a href="#tab-work_log" id="tab_work_log"><span>Work Log &nbsp;
   <img id="update_work_log_link" src="/images/small_refresh.png?
      v=420740.386111111&killcache=201108172214" border="0" 
      class="expandable"/>
   <img src="/images/small_load.gif?
      v=420740.386111111&killcache=201108172214" 
      id="update_work_log_indicator" 
      style="display:none;" align="top" />
   </span></a>
</li>
```

the tab im looking for is the tab-correspondence and i can see that my webbrowser is navigating to the page and clicking on the tabs and pasting the data and click 
 the save, however i cannot see data once i load the page. somehow it doesnt being captured

```
    For Each element As HtmlElement In Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All
        If InStr(element.Id, "tab_correspondence") Then
            element.InvokeMember("Click")         
        End If
    Next     
    For Each element As HtmlElement In Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All
        If InStr(element.Name, "correspondence") Then
         element.InnerText = "THis is a sample text"

        End If
    Next
    For Each element As HtmlElement In Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All
        If InStr(element.Id, "left_nav") Then
            element.InvokeMember("Click")
        End If
    Next
    Do Until Me.WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
    For Each element As HtmlElement In Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All
        If InStr(element.Id, "save-button") Then
            element.InvokeMember("Click")
        End If
    Next
```

There seems to be no problem with the ID since I can see the tab being  clicked and data being pasted and saved, however the problem seems to be with the webbrowser or something.

Comment: the exact text area is as below: <textarea name="correspondence" id="correspondence" class="diary_box maxified" onfocus="if($(this).hasClass('minified')){$(this).removeClass('minified').addClass('maxified')}" style="width: 1260px; height: 558px;"></textarea>

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  also see [ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: FYI you can use the [**`WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of writing your own loops for every element (a requirement is that the element you're looking for has its `id` attribute set, though).